# Clustered bar plot

Tags: gnuplot

I've got the following `data.dat` file

```
A  B  C D    E 
1 24 24 1 5.06326e-05
1 12 12 2 9.82645e-05
1  6  6 4 0.000178653
1  3  3 8 0.000326006
2 48 24 1 2.92298e-05
2 24 12 2 6.06926e-05
2 12  6 4 0.000102249
2  6  3 8 0.000184589
```

and I would like to generate a clustered bar plot using `E` column data and against `A` and `D` column data. `A` is the cluster number and `D` is repeated for each cluster. I have managed to get close to the final solution I am after with

```
p "data.dat" u 5:key(1)
```

obtaining 
[image]

However although the data is right, the clusters are not well seen. Is there a way of plotting this using clusters without changing the data format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that it also depends how general input you want to handle. In case that the column `D` always contains for each cluster successive powers of 2, one might be tempted to construct the boxes manually with the `boxes` plotting style:

```
set terminal pngcairo enhanced
set output 'fig.png'

#if your data file contains the header line with A, B, C, D, E
set key autotitle columnhead

set boxwidth 0.5
set style fill solid

f=6
w=0.5

unset key
set style fill empty

unset xtics
set ytics out nomirror

set format y '%.2f'
set label at graph 0,1 "{/Symbol \264}10^{3}" offset character 0.75,-1
plot \
    'data.dat' u ($1*f*w + log($4)/log(2)*w):($5/1e-3) w boxes lc rgb 'dark-red', \
    '' u ($1*f*w + log($4)/log(2)*w):(0):4 w labels offset 0, char 1
```

Here, the variable `w` specifies the desired with of an elementary box. The position of each box is calculated as an offset of the entire cluster `$1*f*w` plus an offset for a particular box `log($4)/log(2)*w`. If column `D` contains numbers 1,2,4,8, etc., then `log($4)/log(2)` gives the "position" of that box inside the corresponding cluster. The result is then:
[image]

Alternatively, another assumption could be that each cluster has the same number of boxes `G`. Then the script could look like:

```
set terminal pngcairo enhanced
set output 'fig.png'

#if your data file contains the header line with A, B, C, D, E
set key autotitle columnhead

set boxwidth 0.5
set style fill solid

f=6
w=0.5
G=4

unset key
set style fill empty

unset xtics
set ytics out nomirror

set format y '%.2f'
set label at graph 0,1 "{/Symbol \264}10^{3}" offset character 0.75,-1
plot \
    'data.dat' u (int($0/G)*f*w + (int($0)%G)*w):($5/1e-3) w boxes lc rgb 'dark-red', \
    '' u (int($0/G)*f*w + (int($0)%G)*w):(0):4 w labels offset 0, char 1
```

The cluster number is calculated as `int($0/G)` using the special column number `0` (giving the 0-based row number in the input data file). In a similar fashion `int($0)%G` yields the position of a particular box within its cluster.